# form input value before Submit the Form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am writing an attendance system, where the name of the person working in a department will be shown and user will select respective attendance through radio buttons. I want to write the attendance record in a mysql data base.
For this i tried to prepare an array where i am unable to pass the value of selected radio button. Please help.
The sample code is as under:

```
<?php 
$qry1="select * from master where office='ECZO_IT' order by cadre desc,srno";
$result1=mysql_query($qry1,$con);

$sl=1;
echo "<form method='post' action=''>";
echo "<table align='center' border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='border-    collapse: collapse' bordercolor='#111111' width='800' id='AutoNumber1' height='219'>";
echo "<tr><th colspan='14' bgcolor='#C0C0C0' align='center'>Attendance Report</th></tr>";
echo "<tr bgcolor='#C0C0C0' align='center'><th>Sl.</th>";
echo "<th >SR No.</th>";
echo "<th>Name</th>";
echo "<th>Designation</th>";
echo "<th colspan='10' align='center'>Attendance</th></tr>";
while ($data=mysql_fetch_row($result1))
{
echo "<tr><td align='center'>$sl</td>";
echo "<td align='center'>$data[0]</td>";
echo "<td>$data[1]</td>";
echo "<td align='center'>$data[4]</td>";
echo "<td bgcolor='#C0C0C0' align='center'>Present</td>";
echo "<td><input type='radio' name='r1[$sl]' value='PRESENT' id='at' checked></td>";
echo "<td bgcolor='#C0C0C0' align='center'>Training</td>";
echo "<td><input type='radio' name='r1[$sl]' value='TRAINING' id='at'></td>";
echo "<td bgcolor='#C0C0C0' align='center'>Tour</td>";
echo "<td><input type='radio' name='r1[$sl]' value='TOUR' id='at'></td>";
echo "<td bgcolor='#C0C0C0' align='center'>Leave</td>";
echo "<td><input type='radio' name='r1[$sl]' value='LEAVE' id='at'></td>";
echo "<td bgcolor='#C0C0C0' align='center'>Absent</td>";
echo "<td><input type='radio' name='r1[$sl]' value='ABSENT' id='at'></td></tr>";
$out[]= array ('srno' => $data['0'], 'ename' => $data[1], 'att' => $_POST['r1']);
$sl=$sl+1;
}
echo "</table>";
echo "<p align='center'><input type='submit' name ='s1' value='Submit'></p>";
echo "</form>";
foreach($out as $row)
{
echo $row['srno'].'----'.$row['ename'].'----'.$row['att']."<br/>";
}
?>
```

Please suggest if there is any other way out

### Notes:

I tried to change the array as under

```
$out = array ('srno' => $data['0'], 'ename' => $data[1], 'att' => $_POST['r1']);
```

before modification the result was like this:

343587----SUNIL PRASAD OJHA----Array

343607----MUKESH KUMAR JHA----Array

343701----PRABHAT RANJAN----Array

After modification the result was as under:
3----3----3

P----P----P

I also tried to check output through the following code in foreach loop:

```
echo var_dump($out['att']);
```

but the result shows NULL only

Please help

Comment: You can concatenate echos e.g. `echo "</table><p align='center'..."`, or even just combine the strings using `"string"."string"`

Answer (score 0):

I can access your radio button's value through:

```
var_dump($out[0]['att']);
```

Correct your array this way:

```
 $out = array ('srno' => $data['0'], 'ename' => $data[1], 'att' => $_POST['r1']); //removed [] from $out
```

to accces it as:

```
 echo $out['att'][1];
```

The 1 is because your radio buttons are an input array and your $sl value is 1

I have no idea why you need the foreach loop but you can also use it this way:

```
$data[1]='test';
$data2[1]='test2';
$out= array ('srno' => $data, 'ename' => $data2, 'att' => $_POST['r1']);
$i=1;
foreach($out as $key=>$val)
{
echo $key.'='.$val[$i]."<br/>";
}

//Prints: srno=test
//        ename=test2
//        att=TRAINING
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. But when i changed $out[] to $out display has been changed as under:

Comment: Under? If it's a long comment, you can edit it in your above post as a note.